# Pivot table in Pandas to "unmelt" values in specified column into individual columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, melt

I have a Pandas data frame:

```
timestamp   device_id   metric_name     metric_value
2020-10-20  6C0301      throughput      5.0
2020-10-21  6C0301      throughput      6.3
2020-10-20  6C0301      cache           4.7
2020-10-21  6C0301      cache           2.1
2020-10-20  6C0302      throughput      1.4
2020-10-21  6C0302      throughput      1.8
2020-10-22  6C0302      blocks          9.3
2020-10-23  6C0302      blocks          7.2
```

So different devices at different times, each with their own set of metric_names and metric_values.

I need to produce a table that looks like this:

```
timestamp   device_id   throughput   cache   blocks   
2020-10-20  6C0301      5.0          4.7     NULL
2020-10-21  6C0301      6.3          2.1     NULL
2020-10-20  6C0302      1.4          NULL    NULL
2020-10-21  6C0302      1.8          NULL    NULL
2020-10-22  6C0302      NULL         NULL    9.3
2020-10-23  6C0302      NULL         NULL    7.2
```

So the values in the metric_name column gets "unmelted" into its own individual columns.

I am looking at Pandas [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) but it gives me wrong result:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values='metric_name', index=['timestamp', 'device_id'], columns=['metric_value'])
```

Tells me "DataError: No numeric types to aggregate" even though the metric_value column is float, and I am not looking to aggregate anything.

Comment: Use `df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='metric_value', index=['timestamp', 'device_id'], columns='metric_name')`

Comment: swap columns and values parameters

Comment: This is really close, although it produces multiple indexes. one of which has both an index and column name on top of each other(?)....Any way to only have regular index?

Comment: add `.reset_index()`

Comment: All together `df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='metric_value', index=['timestamp', 'device_id'], columns='metric_name').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: Or use `df.set_index(["timestamp", "device_id", "metric_name"]).unstack("metric_name")`.

Comment: @jezrael Yes, that last one did it, except I also had to add aggfunt='first'

Comment: @HenryYik - yop, it is another way if no aggregation, or `df = pd.pivot(df, values='metric_value', index=['timestamp', 'device_id'], columns='metric_name')`

Comment: I think `aggfunc=first` is possible use, but then is possible data lost, if duplicates. So if no problem. do it.

Comment: @jezrael It won't run without it. It shows error "no numeric types to aggregate" if no aggregation provided. See end of question.

Comment: ya, there is typo - swapped `values='metric_name' `and `columns=['metric_value']` to `values='metric_value'` and `columns='metric_name'`

Comment: @jezrael This is what works: pd.pivot_table(df, values='metric_value', index=['timestamp', 'device_id'], columns='metric_name', aggfunc='first').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

Comment: @Cybernetic - Yop, I hope so.

Comment: @jezrael Add it as answer if you want the points.

Comment: No, I think it is all in dupe, so rather not.